# Laravel send notification to android using firebase

Tags: laravel

i am sending notification to android using backend as laravel through firebase but i get error as "append .json to your request URI to use the REST API." Using Postman i am runing this api

```
This is function which is used to get notification in json in my controller

public function sendNotification(Request $req)
{
        $fcmUrl = 'https://playout-52d1f.firebaseio.com';
        $token=$req->input('token');
        $title=$req->input('title');

        $notification = [
            'title' => $title,
            'sound' => true,
        ];

        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=AIzaSyDF4_rqij_Bt4zC3GNEVbNFvwX1HHxy5Mo',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

       dd($result );

}
```

Comment: I would suggest sending your request using Guzzle library instead of curl.  It's super clean, and allows you to send all types of requests.  There are also Notification Channels for Firebase that are built to be used with Laravel

Comment: hello @JoeGalind in my code notification can not send to device...